# My console app stops listening for input when I open another window

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm writting application that moves my cursor down when i press a button on keyboard. When I open another window, like for example paint, it doesn't check if my button is pressed. Simply it stops working when other app is focused.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdio>



int main()
{
    WM_KILLFOCUS;
    bool start = false;
    bool open = true;
    int n = 0;
    POINT p;
    
    while (open)
    {
        start = false;
        n = 0;
        GetCursorPos(&p);
        char c = _getch();
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD0))
            open = false;

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD1))
        {
            start = true;
            while (start)
            {
                if (n == 30)
                    start = false;
                Sleep(25);
                GetCursorPos(&p);
                SetCursorPos(p.x, p.y + 10);
                n++;
            }

        }
        
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is to be expected. There's a call to [`_getch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch) that will not return unless there is console input. If the console isn't the foreground window then it won't get any input.

Comment: Thank you, I removed it. Now it works perfectly

Comment: For some definition of *"perfect"*, I suppose. You need to pay closer attention when reading [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate). Also, polling is *always* inferior to an event-based solution, such as a low-level keyboard hook.